# Capturing system or app audio with AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

*I'm not an up-to-date mobile dev, so please excuse me.  I was talking with a friend and am curious.  I have audio experience but not modern swift+ios experience.*

Let's say I had a view with a youtube player embedded.  The swift players I have found (pods etc) don't seem to expose like an audio channel as a stream or object.  For example:

```
// from the pod swift-audio-player

// Import Swift module
import YouTubePlayer
@IBOutlet var videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView!
// init YouTubePlayerView w/ playerFrame rect (assume playerFrame declared)
var videoPlayer = YouTubePlayerView(frame: playerFrame)
// Load video from YouTube ID
videoPlayer.loadVideoID("nfWlot6h_JM")
```

The player has functions for controlling playback but not anything low level.  Let's assume you could get the mpeg stream through a different library and you had access to the audio stream with `mpegStream.audioChannels()`.

How could you approach integrating this with `AudioKit`?  I understand how to mix/capture nodes from the docs but where would you plug in the video player's stream?

Would you look for things that are compatible with AVFoundation and then attach a sampler?

```
// assume some library here
let mpeg = mpegStream.audioChannels()

// do audiokit sampling here and be able to capture audio
// like a karaoke machine / audio editor / sampler / sound board
import AudioKit

// attach node to mixer ??
// What interface could I look for?  AVFoundation stream?  Does AudioKit do that?

// from here .. I am clear with concepts.
// AudioKit lets you capture/route/modify audio in buffers just like
// A DAW or how SoundFlower works.
```

My question really is, what's the wiring between a youtube player or mpeg stream and AudioKit?  I can't figure out what AudioKit wants or what a realistic common interface would be.  I guess it depends on how the youtube stream is fetched, but could you get an mpeg stream raw without these high level player pods/libraries maybe?  Then I'd just look for an AVFoundation interface (get an AVFoundation type, pass in an AVFoundation type to AudioKit somehow)?

Answer (score 1):

AudioKit does not currently support streaming media.